# How can we access Node server outside the network if the app is listening on 'localhost'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, deployment

Using Express when we use `app.listen(port)` , the app location is `localhost:port/`

In local machine I completely understand how we can access to this address as we use a local browser running on same machine . Even other clients running on same network can access the server.

As per my knowledge `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` IP can be accessed on same or other machines in same network.

But if we deploy to cloud like Heroku without adding IP option like `app.listen(port, IP_ADDRESS)` instead we use `app.listen(port)`, the only thing that varies is PORT number(process.env.PORT) but IP is still localhost. So how can clients from other networks access the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use port forwarding on your router to forward `router_ip:port` to `local_ip:port` allowing you to access it externaly

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are connecting to your local instance via localhost doesn't mean it is not also exposed via IP. Localhost basically says don't resolve any IP, just loop back to this computer, but your node server will still be deployed to an actual IP address. Try looking up your computer's IP address and connecting to your node server through that instead of localhost, and you'll find you're still able to communicate with the server.

When deploying to a cloud service, or any other hosting service, you'll be given an IP address associated with that instance which is what will be used for resolving. Heroku in particular will blackbox a lot of the domain-space and port-forwarding process for you.